# BI Answers/OBIEE- Create Filter on column without impacting Row results

Tags: sql, oracle, obiee

I want to get the total number of projects completed in < 5, and < 10 duration days
I have a measure/fact column to give me the total completed projects.
I don't have a measure column for less than < 5 or < 10 days

I have a separate folders for the dimension which has each individual projects details with date, Days to complete etc..

I can create a filter however then I am restricted to all data less than 5 days. I just want these columns to give me total figures.

Do I need to create some type of sub query or cross join to achieve this?

```
SELECT
"Mytbl"."Fact_Projects"."Average_Project_Time" s_1
"Mytbl"."Fact_Projects"."Completed" s_2
FROM "Mytbl"
```

Looking for a table to look like the following:

```
Average Project Time|Completed|Completed in 5 days or less| Completed in 10 days or less|
20|100|20|80|
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use selection steps. They don't impact the WHERE clause and don't cut off your data stream:
https://obieeil.blogspot.com/2015/01/obiee-understanding-selection-steps.html

https://gerardnico.com/dat/obiee/obips/selection_step

Comment: Thanks for that, will give that a go.